# Minify js in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.2, requirejs-config.js

I have added script in phtml file for faq (cms page).

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
    ],
            function ($) {
                $(".faqs-question").click(function () {console.log($(this).next());
                    $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: block');
                    $(".faqs-answer").attr('style', 'display: none');
                });

            });
</script>
```

After minifying js the click event not working properly in chromium...it takes double click to open faqs..

But in firefox its working correctly.

How to fix the problem

If anyone faced these type of issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add your script inside document.ready like :

```
$(document).ready(function($){     
   $(".faqs-question").click(function () {
        console.log($(this).next());
        $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: block');
        $(".faqs-answer").attr('style', 'display: none');    
   }); 
});
```

It might solve your problem.
Thanks

Comment: Also clear your browser cache,  it might also be a case.

Comment: Still Not working...

Comment: I have remove one extra comma from that script, also i have tested it into my cms page using same way you did and its working for me into all browser.

Try below script it might help you:

<script>
    require(['jquery'],function ($) {
        $(".faqs-question").click(function () {
            console.log('done');                    
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: I can able to get console.log in all browser .But the faq question not open in first click

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240222/accordion-in-magento2

Comment: Pls Can u explain clearly ....

Comment: Actually problem is in your script because, 
on click of 'faqs-question' class your script is doing following :

$(this).next().attr('style', 'display: block');
This means it will add display block for next element and next element is 'faqs-answer'.

Now second is 
$(".faqs-answer").attr('style', 'display: none');
This will also add css property display none to class 'faqs-answer'.

So both script code work for same class 'faqs-question' so on click 'faqs-question' class it will add display block and then again add display none based on you code.

Please update your script.
Thanks

Comment: Let me know if anything.

Comment: But same code working in developer mode

Comment: Yeah, but after merge JS it might faced actual error and it might possible it was ignoring into developer mode.

Comment: Yes that was my point, so you have to modify your script, it is not a problem of browser.

Comment: Ok ... i will try to do that